# What data visualization control is used to present the results in LINQPad?

Tags: .net, linq, linqpad

What data visualization control is used to present the results in [LINQPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQPad)? Or is there any alternative for showing hierarchical data in .NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQPad uses a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control to display a dynamically generated HTML page. You can even view its source code by right clicking on the results window. So it's basically a wrapper around Internet Explorer. As far as the generation of the HTML is concerned it uses a custom built XhtmlFormatter to visit the object graph and emit XHTML based on XDocument.

Answer (score 3):

LINQPad can also call all the old [Dundas charting controls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dundas_Data_Visualization#Dundas_products) that come with Windows Forms. Just dump any Bitmap object and LINQPad dutifully displays it in the HTML. Try out the following, making sure you have `System.Drawing`, `System.Windows.Forms`, and `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization`, in your <kbd>F4</kbd> references, paste and hit <kbd>F5</kbd>. It also works with the higher-level SHO charts, which have been tailored for [IronPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronPython), but work great from C#.

```
// Almost the smallest meaningful example of Charting
void Main()
{
    // Chart must have a chart area, but it's not externally referenced later
    var chartArea1 = new ChartArea();
    var chart1 = new Chart();
    chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);

    var series1 = new Series();

    // The following goes beyond the minimal, but just a little. You can delete these two lines.
    // Fun to set the series ChartType; default is column chart
    series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
    series1.CustomProperties = "LabelsRadialLineSize=1, PieDrawingStyle=Concave, LabelStyle=outside";

    var r = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
    var ys = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select (e => r.NextDouble()).Dump("Doubles");
    var xs = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select (e => GetRandomString(3).ToUpper()).Dump("Strings");
    series1.Points.DataBindXY(xs.ToArray(), ys.ToArray());
    chart1.Series.Add(series1);

    var b = new Bitmap(width: chart1.Width, height: chart1.Height);
    chart1.DrawToBitmap(b, chart1.Bounds);
    b.Dump();

    var frm = new Form();
    // Seems 300 x 300 is the default chart-area size and chart size, so set the form to hold it
    frm.ClientSize = new Size(width: 300, height: 300);
    frm.Controls.Add(chart1);

    Application.Run(frm);
}

static IEnumerable<string> CharRange(Char c, int length)
{
    return (from e in Enumerable.Range(Convert.ToInt32(c), length)
            select Char.ConvertFromUtf32(e));
}

static string GetRandomString(int length)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    do
        sb.Append(Path.GetRandomFileName().Replace(".", "").Substring(0, length < 11 ? length : 11));
    while ((length -= 11) > 0);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```